# Laravel many-to-many

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I've Googled for a while and found multiple threads discussing problems like this, but I just can't get my head around how to do exactly what I want to do, hope someone can point me in the correct direction.

I'm making a learning platform in Laravel. What I want right now is that when lesson A is completed by someone belonging to workplace B a notification should be sent to user C. So I have made a table notification_receivers containing lesson_id, workplace_id, and user_id, pointing to the respective tables.

Of course, I also have the corresponding models (User, Lesson, Workplace) set up, but what I can't understand is exactly how to set up the model relations. I'm currently making the Blade template used for editing the notification receivers belonging to a particular lesson, and I need to make the following: Get all notification receiver users for this lesson and then for every one of those users, get the related workplaces.

My first try was this in the Lesson model:

```
public function notification_receivers(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'notification_receivers')->withPivot(["workplace_id"]);
}
```

Which of course doesn't work straight off, since some users will be returned multiple times (once for each workplace). How do I do to get every user just once?

And when I have my users, how do I get the workplaces for each user? If I get it to work, the `withPivot` above will give me the IDs, but how do I get a collection of the Workplaces?

Comment: You might need [many to many polymorphic](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations)

Comment: or you can try this https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

Comment: this is my example code: 
.
public function payment_methods()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Models\PaymentMethod', '\App\Models\BranchPaymentMethod');
    }

Comment: @mrobbizulfikar Share this code and a little more insight as an answert, not a comment please.